# Xcode is just an IDE

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248422/network-access-in-ios
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248272/need-help-with-kballard-rss-parser
[UIImageView /UIImage Not Working - What Am I Doing Wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247827/uiimageview-uiimage-not-working-what-am-i-doing-wrong)
...

Is anyone else annoyed that questions tagged [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) more often than not have nothing at all to do with Xcode? I've edited it out of a few posts, but was wondering if anyone else had *big tools* that could more easily remove tags from posts? Is the pollution in the tag too far gone to even try to fight it?

Comment: It maybe a problem if one actually have a problem with XCode.

Comment: @Yet Another: Indeed; a quick scan of the questions tagged `[xcode]` shows roughly 7 out of the first 50 questions actually had something to do with Xcode. The other 43 were iOS/Objective-C/Cocoa questions. Is that too polluted to even try to clean?

Comment: This is a problem with the "Visual Studio" tag, too. (And the "visual" tag, which apparently comes from people trying to type in "Visual Studio.) But there are *some* questions that are actually *about* the IDEs. Removing the tags isn't the solution. Not sure how we automate the fix. I remove the inappropriate tags manually when I come across the question.

Answer (score 5):

The reason the problem is so pronounced here is that Xcode has an extremely strong association with iOS development, to the point that in many people's minds, it's virtually synonymous with the iOS SDK. Indeed it's virtually impossible to build a complex application without spending at least some time in Xcode. And Apple is in no small way responsible for this confusion, as their messaging doesn't really make a distinction.

Trying to solve this particular case is probably an exercise in futility. Random (visual) sampling shows better than 50% of the questions are probably not at all Xcode-specific, meaning there are 6000+ questions so mis-tagged, out of 12,000+ (but there are surely thousands of valid Xcode questions in there, too).

There is no good way to automate the retroactive fix, someone(s) would just have to slog through, and maintaining the distinction is going to be a serious long-term problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I've edited it out of a few posts,
>   but was wondering if anyone else had
>   big tools that could more easily
>   remove tags from posts

I don't think that's a good idea. It's like trying to do gardening with a bulldozer. Just let the community take care of that. Keep in mind that:

Anyone with 500+ rep can [retag questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions). 
Even having less than 500 rep, one can still make [edit suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), which can also include retagging. These will be reviewed and most likely accepted.

So anyone can just remove the [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) and write *"not related to xcode"* in edit summary.