# Batch tag remove for 20k+ users and/or diamond moderators (or similar to how tag synonyms works today)

Tags: feature-request, tags

I was trying to remove a tag, [explanation](/questions/tagged/explanation), from the StackOverflow site. I can do all 60 some questions manually, but I've seen similar tags which are completely useless before.

Would it be possible to get a tool to eliminate this manual labor? (Don't care if it's for diamond moderators or 20k+ -- just would like it to be possible)

**EDIT**: This would also work using the existing tag synonym system. However, there are some tags that are just garbage, and need to die. Completely. In such cases, one should be able to suggest that a tag be nuked completely.

Comment: It used to be possible for diamond mods and it went away; I'm not sure if that was an intentional "we don't want them doing this anymore" or just an oversight when something else changed

Comment: +1:, it's a feature I'd like to have to help cleanup the `[xcode]` tag when my 20k day comes. :)

Comment: @sarnold: You should be already able to clean up an existing tag -- just suggest synonyms. It's only outright nuking of a tag that's not supported today.

Comment: @Billy, a synonym can't remove it from questions where it was never appropriate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93974/xcode-is-just-an-ide

Comment: @sarnold: The proposed feature wouldn't help you there either. Anyone with edit privies can already nuke as many taggings as they wish. How would you propose automagically detecting cases where it's wrong?

Comment: @Billy, I primarily want an interface that doesn't require loading every question individually to edit. I'd love to see the listing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode annotated with a checkbox next to every question and a button at the top and bottom of the list that says _Delete this tag from the checked questions_. While one can't be certain on _all_ of them, there are definitely questions where the applicability is obvious even from the overview.

Comment: @sarnold: That's a different feature request. You should request it. :)

Comment: To clarify, there are 2 things that can currently be done to tags:  merges and synonyms.  A merge renames a tag on all *existing* questions but doesn't touch future questions.  A synonym renames a tag on all *future* questions, but doesn't touch existing questions.  I'm not sure how synonyms covers your feature request.

Comment: @Rebecca: 1. It was my understanding that when a synonym is created, it implicitly performed a merge. Perhaps I was incorrect. 2. I was suggesting adding this to the existing synonym system; i.e. allowing people to vote for whether a tag is deleted rather than giving a single user absolute deletion power.

Comment: @Billy, until this conversation, I wasn't aware that you _didn't_ want a checkbox next to every question in a `[tag]` search request. :)

Comment: @sarnold: I'm saying just "find all instances of tag XYZ and remove that tag." The only implementation problem I could see here would be that if XYZ is the only tag on the question, it would have to be given a tag like "untagged", or somehow be manually reviewed first.

Comment: No, a merge is a separate action.  Still though, with both a merge and a synonym, you're renaming one tag into another.  You have to have a destination tag.  A tag can't be eliminated with either of those.  Your title says "exactly like tag synonyms work today".

Comment: @Rebecca: Edited. Better?

Comment: Uh, no?  Tag synonyms don't remove anything.  So saying "exactly like" or "similar to" synonyms when you're asking to remove something confuses me.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Rebecca: But tag synonyms require XX rep to be voted on/suggested, require community voting, are show specially in the moderation tools, etc. I believe the fact that things would be getting removed is covered in the "Batch tag remove" part of the title.

Comment: I thought there was a post on here that talked about it's removal. Something along the lines of the fact that it couldn't be undone, and they didn't want any tags accidentally deleted. I suspect that for them to reintroduce this, and several other requested tag management features, they would first have to build a rollback solution into the system. For now, if it's truly onerous and truly should be nuked, discuss it here and email the team. They can perform such dangerous commands that even the mods can't.