# Tool/IDE-related tags; Are they only for questions specifically about the tool/IDE?

Tags: discussion, tags

I sometimes edit out tool/IDE tags from questions like this:

[Creating a dynamic 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272696/creating-a-dynamic-2d-array)

This question originally had the [visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010) tag on it, but I removed it. I usually do this in these cases because the question is not really about the IDE itself; it is just about code that the OP *happens* to be writing in that IDE.

My understanding is that these tags are just for questions *about* the tool specifically; such as problems using the IDE, or perhaps developing an extension for that IDE. In some cases, questions about code that is affected specifically by the IDE might count, as well.

Am I correct here?

Comment: I've been doing that with some of the obscene amount of `eclipse` tags in the Android area, so I hope you're right.

Comment: See also [Xcode is just an IDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93974/xcode-is-just-an-ide). I retag all of these I find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you are correct. Tags should:

- Make it easier to find questions
- Make it easier to filter questions
- Clarify the meaning of posts

Such tags do none of those, and thus are irrelevant, and can be removed.